# Error during Angular-cli installation

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/linux-x64-51_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/linux-x64-51_binding.node":

ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

```
  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
```

or configure npm proxy via

```
  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

> node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-51/binding.node
Testing binary
Bus error (core dumped)
/usr/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.8 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 135
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are behind a proxy, you should get binairy locally and tell npm where it is located:

See https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters

Easiest is to download the file to your disk and tell npm where it is

Comment: It is because of a proxy. But the library you mention is currently deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites of Node & NPM version are not met,

As stated in the error log update your node & NPM Versions.

```
Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Download latest Node JS version & You can upgrade npm via

```
npm ugrade npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

First run, `node -v` and `npm -v` and **make sure that you have at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x**.

If this is fine with you, then you need to clean your npm cache.

Do this by running,

```
npm cache clean
```

Then run,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the [Quickstart guide of angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), installed node (v6.11.3) and npm and upgraded npm (to v5.4.2). But when I do

`ng new my-app`

I get a similar error message:

> ...
>   Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/linux-x64-48_binding.node":
>
> ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
>
> ...
>
> Package install failed, see above.

Despite I can access github.com in my browser, I cannot download the file located at the given URL (neither in my browser nor on the command line). But here it comes: On my root server (different IP address, different ISP) I can download this file without any problems.

I renewed my internet connection several times in order to get a different internet IP address but it didn't work, either. At work, colleagues of mine had similar problems. Thus, **I conclude that github overblocked some IP address ranges**.

Answer (score -1):

Do this by running

```
sudo apt install ng-common
```

then run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```